# Running LaraDock on Mac Silicon computer (MacBook Pro 2021) with Docker Desktop gives Apache2_1 exited with code 2

Tags: apache, apple-m1, laradock

On a Mac Silicon computer (MacBook Pro 2021):

1. git clone git@github.com:laradock/laradock.git
2. cd laradock
3. cp .env.example .env
4. docker-compose build workspace
5. docker-compose build apache2
6. docker-compose up apache2 workspace ------> **Apache2_1 exited with code 2**

Running **Docker Desktop for Apple M1 (v.4.3.0)** on **MacOS Monterey 12.01**

Answer (score 4):

Fount the solution myself. This was the solution:

Edit: /apache2/Dockerfile

```
*// First line, edit it like this:*
FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 webdevops/apache:ubuntu-18.04

*// At the end of the file, add this:*
RUN wget -O "/usr/local/bin/go-replace" "https://github.com/webdevops/goreplace/releases/download/1.1.2/gr-arm64-linux" \
    && chmod +x "/usr/local/bin/go-replace" \
    && "/usr/local/bin/go-replace" --version
```

Then do this:

**docker-compose build apache2**

**docker-compose up apache2**

Result: Apache is running fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest **Laradock**, you should go to the directory of **Apache2**, you should see a file called '**Dockerfile**', open that file with VS Code or any IDE.

At about line 34, there is a flag that says:

```
ARG APACHE_FOR_MAC_M1=false
```

you should change the line to true, it should look like this;

```
ARG APACHE_FOR_MAC_M1=true
```

After changing this you must run in the terminal the following commands:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache apache2
```

and

```
docker-compose up -d apache2
```

After that, it should work!